# Parallels and meridians

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the surface patches $$\sigma (u, v) = (\text{cosh } u \cos v, \text{cosh } u \sin v, u), \ \ \tilde{\sigma}(u, v)=(u \cos v, u \sin v, v)$$ 
parametrizing a catenoid and a helicoid, respectively.

I have shown that the map from the catenoid to the helicoid that takes $\sigma (u, v)$ to $\tilde{\sigma}(\text{sinh } u, v)$ is a local isometry.

I have to find which curves on the helicoid correspond under this isometry to the parallels and meridians of the catenoid.

$$$$

I have done the following:

The profile curve is $\gamma (u)=(\text{cosh } u, 0, u)$, right?

To find the parallels and meridians we set $u=\text{constant}$ and $v=\text{constant}$, or not?

Therefore, the parallels correspnd to the curves $$\tilde{\sigma}(u_0, v)=(u_0 \cos v, u_0 \sin v, v)$$ and the meridians correspond to the curves $$\tilde{\sigma}(u, v_0)=(u \cos v_0, u \sin v_0, v_0)$$ right?

What kind of curves are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done looks correct, to me.

The curve $v \mapsto \bar\sigma(u_0,v)$ is a helix. As $v$ increases, the $(x,y)$ values lie on the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = u_0^2$, and the $z$-value increases linearly. So, the helix has the $z$-axis as its centerline, and it has radius $u_0$.

The curve $v \mapsto \bar\sigma(u_0,v)$ is a straight line. It can be written
$$
\bar\sigma(u_0,v) = (0,0,v_0) + u(\cos v_0, \sin v_0, 0)
$$
So, it's a straight line through the point $(0,0,v_0)$ in the direction of the vector $(\cos v_0, \sin v_0, 0)$.

Comment: I read now again the formulation of the exercise and I got stuck... "Which curves on the helicoid correspond under this isometry to the parallels and meridians of the catenoid." So we find the parallels and the merdians of the helicoid, or not? Or do we have to find the parallels and the merdians of the catenoid?

Comment: A helicoid doesn't have parallels and meridians, as far as I know. So, I suppose the question wants you to find the parallels and meridians of the catenoid, and map those through the isometry. What you did is correct, I think. So, in the end, all you're really doing is finding the $u=\text{constant}$ and $v=\text{constant}$ curves on the helicoid.

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-)